# Hacer un UPDATE DENTRO DE UN While con SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Hola buen dia necesito ayuda para corregir unos datos en mi base de datos ando haciendo pruebas pero no hice un bak entonces procedi a borrar los datos pero tengo un problema muy especifico, lo que quiero hacer es cambiar el valor de un campo solo en algunos registros de esa tabla haciendo referencia de otra tabla

el codigo que estoy desarrollando es el siguiente:

```
declare @id_empleado int = (select count(*) from Empleado_insumo where day(fecha_alta) = day(getdate()) 
and month(fecha_alta) = month(getdate()) 
and year(fecha_alta) = year(getdate()))
select @id_empleado

while (@id_empleado > 0)
begin


update Posisiones set id_empleado = null 
where id_empleado = (select top 1 id_empleado_plant  from Empleado_insumo where day(fecha_alta) = day(getdate()) 
and month(fecha_alta) = month(getdate()) 
and year(fecha_alta) = year(getdate()))



end
```

Pero no hace nada y por lo tanto no avanza en la instrucción, no se si alguien me pueda ayudar, esto empezo por que no puedo hacer un update con un resultado mayor a un valor 1

gracias por la ayuda xd

Comment: Puede serte de interés realizar leer [ask], sobre todo la parte de crear un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible. Por otro lado, aunque no parece necesario utilizar un bucle para esto, y suponiendo que prefieras hacerlo así. La variable que gobierna el bucle nunca cambia de valor. Lo que tenga antes de entrar, sea cual sea, nunca se ve modificada. El `count` lo haces de `Empleado_insumo`, pero el update lo haces de `Posiciones`. Aunque dentro del bucle metieras otra vez el `Set variable`, esta cuenta siempre dará lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cambiar el `begin` por `do` y el `end` por `end while`

```sql
while (@id_empleado > 0)
DO

update Posisiones set id_empleado = null  where id_empleado = (select top 1 id_empleado_plant  from Empleado_insumo where day(fecha_alta) = day(getdate())  and month(fecha_alta) = month(getdate())  and year(fecha_alta) = year(getdate()))

END WHILE
```

Comment: No reonoce la sintaxis de DO y END While en sql server

Comment: Has comprobado que la variable `@id_empleado` sea mayor a 0?

Comment: si ya lo solucione de manera parcial solo hacia falta un delete from empleado_insumo where id_empleado_plant = (select top 1 * from Empleado_insumo  y las demas condiciones para que hiciera un for continuo y ya llegando a 0 deja de preguntar, por que asi solo hace el update y sigue encontrando el mismo resultado xd